# How do you translate "budget" into Chinese from this context?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word, sentence-structure, sentence

**Budget** can be translated as "**预算**", this translation sounds more like a verb for preestimate.
While budgeted expenses can be translated as "**预算费**".

However, I am unsure if either fits into the follow context:
"The current *budget* for my student employment is running low. Therefore, my boss has applied for a award increase request. My student employment allocation was increased by $1000. With this, I can work a few more weeks."

---

Furthermore, I notice "**经费**" (**funds**) can be a good fit into this as well.

Comment: After brainstorming, I am more incline that "经费" (funds) would be great in this context. As it works as a great fit, without being forced to literally use the Chinese term of "budget". As context differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"fund"(经费) is a fund you use to operate; "budget"(预算) is a fund you committed to an operation.

> The current budget for my student employment is running low.

It should be  "fund" instead of "budget" in the first place.

- Funds (经费) can run out at any stage
- committed funds (预算) can only be not enough in the first place

Comment: I see. I do notice that they may have mixed "budget" with “funds”. It happens sometimes with 表音文字。